# How to parse BeautifulSoup results for a specific word to define a boolean?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to take `BeautifulSoup` results and parse them for a specific word which I will define whether a certain value is `True` or `False`. For example, if I parse with `BeautifulSoup` for a specific `id` element and it contains the word "yes", then `bool1 = True`. If the specific `id` element contains the word "no", than `bool1 = false`.

This is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

parse_only = SoupStrainer('h1')
page1 = requests.get('http://www.play-hookey.com/htmltest/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page1.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=parse_only)

results1 = soup.find_all('h1')

print(results1)
```

I am trying to then parse `results1` for a specific word and if it contains that word, then the boolean will either be `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search if the word you want is in the `.text()` of the `results1` object:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.play-hookey.com/htmltest/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

results1 = soup.find_all("h1")

# This will return True if found a match else False
print(any("WORD I'M LOOKING FOR" in tag.text.split() for tag in results1))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! After I read the document I saw BS4 had a get_text() method as well which I believe could work. Thanks again.